# Zip Utilities with Queue Functionality

Tags: windows-7, windows, zip, 7-zip

Are there any programs similar to 7zip or PeaZip that support a "queue" functionality? I have multiple large files to unzip, and I would like to add them all to one single queue and have them synchronously extract.

I find that if I unzip them all at the same time, it takes quite a while longer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

[WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/) can do this.
In the extract window, go to the "Advanced" tab and check "Wait if other WinRAR copies are active".

Answer (score 2):

[PowerArchiver](http://www.powerarchiver.com/) can do this.  It has a queue function that can be enabled to handle queuing up several operations.

It normally operates serially if you select several archives to extract at once, but the queue also lets you queue up several independent actions from Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible tool is [freearc](http://freearc.org) Archiver

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Could you please include a little detail about freearc Archiver in your response? This helps the answer stay useful should the link ever break.